# What exactly is the second parameter to bootstrap()?

Tags: angular

I have an `Api` class to handle all interactions with the server.

```
@Component({
  providers: [Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class Api {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  // functions for different Api end points
}
```

If I wanted to inject the `Api` class into my `Home` component, I'd have something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html',
  providers: [Api, HTTP_PROVIDERS] // specifically this line
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private api: Api) {} // and this line

  ...
}
```

Without `HTTP_PROVIDERS` `Api` won't have `Http` injected. For better or for worse, this lead to me creating `API_PROVIDERS` in my `Api` class so that if it needs more injected into it I won't have to update every place that `Api` is injected (which will probably be most components in the app). This changes things to look like this:

```
// at the bottom of my Api Component
export var API_PROVIDERS = [Api, HTTP_PROVIDERS];

...

// in my Home Component
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html',
  providers: [API_PROVIDERS]
})
```

This works in that I don't get a DI error and my code appears to function. If I however move that provider to my bootstrap call (in boot.ts, the file initially loaded by SystemJS) I get this:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [API_PROVIDERS]);
```

Now I don't need the `providers` property in the `@Component` definition of either my `Home` component or my `Api` component. It seems to just have `Api` and `HTTP_PROVIDERS` made available to everything ready for injection into constructors.

```
// Api Component becomes
@Component({})

// Home Component becomes
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html'
})
```

The injection of `Http` into `Api` works and the injection of `Api` into the `Home` component works as well (they are still arguments in the constructors). The [Angular 2 Api for bootstrap](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform/browser/bootstrap-function.html) states at the bottom of the page that the second parameter is:

> customProviders: An additional set of providers that can be added to the app injector to override default injection behavior.

I don't quite know what that means or what side effects I'll see by including my providers there instead of inside the `@Component` decorators. We probably shouldn't be putting everything we ever want to inject into that bootstrap parameter because then we wouldn't need the `providers` property in `@Component` at all.

What changes when I list my providers in `bootstrap()`'s second parameter instead of the `@Component` decorator? What is that parameter used for?

I'm using the 2.0.0-beta.0 release of Angular 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the [Hierarchical Injectors dev guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html).

At the bootstrap level, you get one instance per app.

At the component level, you get one instance per component.